# Why get pointer to member function inside lambda triggers warning on VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Compile code on visual studio 2013 (with update 5 installed) and using default warning level (/W3)

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    void Thunk()
    {
        auto lambda = [](Foo* f, const char* msg) {
            auto pfn = &Foo::Print;  // complained this statement
            (*f.*pfn)(msg);
        };

        lambda(this, "abc");
    }

    void Print(const char* msg)
    {
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;

    foo.Thunk();

    return 0;
}
```

will trigger a compilation warning:

> Line 16: warning C4573: the usage of 'Foo::Print' requires the
>   compiler to capture 'this' but the current default capture mode does
>   not allow it

However, if I compile this snippet of code on Visual Studio 2017 (ver15.4.2), this warning goes away; and compiling with /W4 warning level still can't reproduce the warning.

Is this an implementation bug of Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: I'm guessing it is. It being an warning instead of error makes it even weirder. [Other compilers on the matter](https://godbolt.org/g/Jd4WdC)

Comment: why not just `f->Print(msg)`?

Comment: @Caleth Because the code snippet above is just a minimum verifiable example. The original version is far more complicated, which involves dispatching the call to an equivalence of Print() onto another thread.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you have default capture options in lambda declaration. Just check **Lambda capture** section [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

I think you should change it with `[=]`

```
auto lambda = [=](Foo* f, const char* msg) {
    auto pfn = &Foo::Print;  // complained this statement
        (*f.*pfn)(msg);
};
```

From the link above, this are the possible capture options:

> captures  -   a comma-separated list of zero or more captures,
>   optionally beginning with a capture-default.
>
> - [a,&b] where a is captured by copy and b is captured by reference.
> - [this] captures the current object (*this) by reference
> - [&] captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by reference and current object by reference if exists
> - [=] captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by copy and current object by reference if exists
> - [] captures nothing
>
> A variable can be used without being captured if it does not have
>   automatic storage duration (i.e. it is not a local variable or it is
>   static or thread local) or if it is not odr-used in the body of the
>   lambda.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. And even if it does, you should explain a link

Comment: Thanks @PasserBy, i hope will be better with this edit

Comment: My original intent was to use capture-less lambda, so the pointer to the instance was passed in as argument

Comment: @KingsleyChen But it seems you're getting `Print` method in such a static way, isn't it?